# How to show "This website needs internet explorer" with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, view, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am working on a site where I want to redirect users to open the site on Internet Explorer if they want to. I saw this somewhere and I want this to show up on my page if users opens the website on WIN Edge. My JavaScript code knows when someone uses Edge, but I want this to show up to those users.

[image]

What should I add to my code to show this?

Answer (score 0):

http://edgetalk.net/why-microsoft-edge-tells-me-this-website-needs-internet-explorer/

This should be my answer. Excuse me for unnecessarily asking this question.

Comment: Link only answers are usually frowned upon because both the link or its content can change over time. Please add the basics to your answer so its safely kept by SO, and link to the original resource.